# Overflow or underflow in the arithmetic operation downloading large files

Tags: reactjs, vb.net, rest, axios

In an application composed by Frontend in React and Backend in VB.Net I have problems downloading files larger than 1GB.
Backend side the function that returns the stream of the file is the following (it works perfectly up to 1 GB)

```vb
<OperationContract()>
<WebGet(UriTemplate:="DownloadAdditionalPackage?f={filename}")>
Function DownloadAdditionalPackage(filename As String) As Stream

Private Function DownloadAdditionalPackage(filename As String) As Stream Implements ILiveUpdateUIWS.DownloadAdditionalPackage
    Dim token = WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.Headers("Authorization")
            
    If ((token IsNot Nothing) AndAlso (token <> String.Empty) AndAlso (LU_Helper.ValidaToken(System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(token), DB_CONNECTION_STRING) = True)) Then
        Try
            Dim downloadFilePath As String = String.Format("{0}\{1}", Path.Combine(DESTINATION_PATH_PACKAGES_COMPLETED, "resources"), filename)
                        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "application/zip"

            Dim fstream = File.OpenRead(downloadFilePath)
            
            Return fstream
        Catch ex As Exception
            TraceLog.WriteToErrorLog(ex.Message, Environment.StackTrace, "Error")
                        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError
            Return Nothing
        End Try
    Else
        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Forbidden
        Return Nothing
    End If
End Function
```

Frontend side I download the file with an Axios call.

```js
        downloadAdditionalPkg = async (filename : string) => {
    
        if (!this.props.userLogged) {
          return [];
        }
    
        let sUrl: string = "";
        sUrl = Links.PROTOCOL + "://" + Links.UIWS + "/DownloadAdditionalPackage?f=" + filename
        let progress = 0;
        this.setState({ percentuale: "" });
        this.setState({ downloading: true });
        
        await axios({
          url: sUrl,
          method: "GET",
          headers: {"Authorization": this.props.userLogged.Token},      
          responseType: "blob",
          maxContentLength: Infinity,                
          onDownloadProgress: (progressEvent) => {
            progress = Math.round((progressEvent.loaded * 100) / progressEvent.total); // you can use this to show user percentage of file downloaded
            this.setState({ percentuale: progress + "%" });
          }
        })
          .then(response => {
            const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
            const link = document.createElement("a");
            link.href = url;
            link.setAttribute("download", filename); //or any other extension
            document.body.appendChild(link);
            link.click();
            this.setState({ downloading: false });
            this.setState({ percentuale: progress });
          })
          .catch(error => {
            this.setState({ downloading: false });
            message.warn("Errore: " + error.message);
            return [];
          });
    
      }
```

If the file has a size > 1 GB the error I get is an error 500. Going to look at the response from the server I see:
overflow or underflow in the arithmetic operation.
How can I solve the problem? Thanks.

Comment: As a test change this progress = Math.round((progressEvent.loaded * 100) / progressEvent.total);  to progress =  progressEvent.total;

Comment: Unfortunately the same problem.

Comment: Which line does it raise the error on?

Comment: There is no specific line that gives the error. The backend function is called, it returns the stream, and after a few seconds we get the arithmetic overflow error (only if the file > 1GB)

Comment: I should have figured out the cause of the problem. In Web.Config, in WebHttpBinding the TransferMode was not set. If it is not set, default value is Buffered and it has the above problem with large files. By setting the value to Streamed the problem no longer occurs. But I noticed that on client side Axios is no longer able to retrieve the total size of the file and shows "Infinity" instead of the progress percentage.

Comment: With "Streamed" TransferMode you need to pass file dimension to the header. Something like this: HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Length", New System.IO.FileInfo(downloadFilePath).Length.ToString())